# How to know the mailbox is empty for unstashing and sending the low priority messages?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I need an actor that stashes low priority messages when receiving and when the mailbox is empty, unstashes the low priority messages and sends them,too.
my mailbox is custom and this is my actor:

```
 class Dispatcher (fileRouter: ActorRef, metaRouter: ActorRef) extends Actor with Stash{

  def receive = {
  case requestQuery  => metaRouter ! requestQuery
  case TrackMeta if sender == metaRouter => fileRouter ! TrackMeta
  case other => stash()
    println("dispatcher buffered")
  }

}
```

I don't know when the mailbox is empty and where( in what method) I should write the unstashing and sending.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The actor is not responsible of managing the messages, it is a dummy in that functionality. The responsible of firing the message to an actor is the dispatcher. You can implement the trait *UnboundedPriorityMailbox*, here you can find the documentation in Akka Doc. [UnboundedPriorityMailbox](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/dispatch/UnboundedPriorityMailbox.html).

```
class CustomPriorityActorMailbox(settings: ActorSystem.Settings, config: Config) extends UnboundedPriorityMailbox(
 PriorityGenerator {

// Int Messages
 case x: requestQuery => 1
 // String Messages
 case TrackMeta => 0
 // Long messages
 case _ => 2
 })
```

In this class, you can define your priorities.

Then you have to set in configuration the new dispatcher configuration.

```
 custom-dispatcher {
     mailbox-type = "com.example.CustomPriorityActorMailbox"

    }
```

Then when creating your actor, you can set your customized dispatcher:

```
val myPriorityActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withDispatcher("custom-dispatcher"))
```

I hope it helps!